# How to modify data in a format-table result?

Tags: powershell

Trying to make a powershell script that tracks link clicks.

I have three goals:

1. change `destination` to `name`
2. Filter out destinations that are not a file type
3. Only display name of file, not the URL or extension

```
# Set the API key and endpoint
$apiKey = "API-KEY"
$endpoint = "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links?&limit=100"

# Make the API call and store the response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{ "apikey" = $apiKey } | Format-Table -Property clicks, destination
$response

clicks destination
------ -----------
    11 https://github.com/file1.ps1
     4 https://github.com/file2.ps1
     2 https://github.com/main.zip
     1 https://www.instagram.com
```

---

***Desired Result***

```
clicks destination
------ -----------
    11 file1
     4 file2
     2 main
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself? You’re not new to powershell or this forum by this point. Please share your attempt(s)

Comment: The code that I tried is actually above, where I asked the question. It showed my results and my desired results.

Comment: I believe Doug asked if you could add to your question your attempt at solving the problem yourself not to add the code I posted as answer to your question

Comment: By the time I get to the point where I ask here I have tried at least 25-50 variations, I understand that maybe I should just post one, but it seems like it would be incredibly cluttered if I posted everything I tried. HOWEVER, from now on I will include an example or two regardless.

Comment: In any case the code provided in my answer has no place in your question and will confused future readers hence I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 0):

`Format-Table` doesn't perform collection filtering hence is not the right cmdlet for this use case. Also, for 2 property objects, it is not needed at all since default formatting output will be a table by default for objects with 4 properties or less.

```bash
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{ "apikey" = $apiKey } | ForEach-Object {
    $lastSegment = ($_.destination -as [uri]).Segments | Select-Object -Last 1
    if([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($lastSegment)) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Clicks = $_.Clicks
            Name   = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($lastSegment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: InvalidOperation:
Line |
   6 |      if([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($uri.Segments[-1])) {
     |         
     | Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: hmmm weird getting no output or errors now

Comment: @IamJakoby assuming you're no longer using `Format-Table` before piping the output from `Invoke-RestMethod` to the loop the code should work fine

Comment: Question edited with current attempt. 

p.s. while you are here, what resources have you used to get where you are?

Comment: well I'm just going to run through your code line by line and see what I can figure out. 
You are appreciated.

Comment: I do not know why, but I could not get your answer to work, no matter what I did the `$lastSegment` variable was always empty. So I used a for loop instead. 
Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of Santiagos answer.
I couldn't quite get his to work.
I'm sure this can be optimized however.

```
$apiKey = "API-KEY"
$endpoint = "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links?&limit=100"

$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{ "apikey" = $apiKey } 
    ForEach($l in $r){$s = ($l.destination -as [uri]).Segments[-1]
        if([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($s)) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
            Clicks = $l.Clicks
            Name   = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($s)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference in your code other than changing the loop to a `foreach` instead of `ForEach-Object` and reusing part of my previous edit. If this works my code also works and your answer is not providing anything useful.

Comment: Look I really appreciate all the help you've given me over time but I'm not sure where this current attitude is coming from. If it worked I would have just used it like all your other suggestions that have been a blessing. I spent hours last night trying to find out why it wasn't working and was not successful, so I went an alternate route.

Comment: I studied your code, broke it down line by line. Looked up every single thing I didn't know. Rehashed and re executed every line individually until it worked. Literally spent hours just trying to make sure I understood it.